# Standardization for using two similar data sets

Tags: t-test, standardization, exploratory-data-analysis

I need your advice regarding standardization:
I have collected two similar datasets from the same population:

1. Error count and time for a group that was tested in person.
2. Error count and time for a group that was asked very similar questions in an online questionnaire.

Both types were completed by two experiment groups that were trained in different ways. However, as the sample size of each combination is relatively small, I would like to combine the data collected in person and online (1&2) for each treatment group so that I can compare (t-test) the standardized value for errors and time across both types of measurements. I wonder

1. whether this is an acceptable approach,
2. which tests I would need to perform (e.g. for normal distribution?) so that I can use the described approach and
3. how I would standardize exactly.

Regarding 3, I am aware of this formula:
[image: Z formula]. Would this be the right one?

Thank you very much in advance for your answer!

Comment: Your standardisation formula confuses random variables and observations. I think you actually mean $\frac{x-\bar x}{s}$, where $\bar x, s$ are sample mean and sample standard deviation. Also you haven't exactly explained what you want to standardise. Is your idea to standardise the in person and online data separately in order to make them "fit for putting them together" as if they would then be a single sample? Even though I see how this could make some sense, I'd find it still hard to argue that after having done that one could use the two modes of testing as if they were the same.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I meant your formula and agree on that.

The idea is to standardize them separately. I see your point but I believe that the differences between groups should only be caused by the treatment group after standardizing for each test's characteristics. Have you ever come across anything similar or have further advise how I could implement this?

Comment: The thing is, it might be that the group tested in person is on average really better or worse (or otherwise different) than the group tested online, either because of random variation (small sample size), or for some systematic reason that I can't know. I'd probably try to standardise them knowing and using the difficulty of the questions (a percentage score might do), and then run an ANOVA with both the treatment groups and in person/online as factors. This allows you to test for effect of treatment over both test modes, and also to test for mode and interaction effects.

Comment: @Lewian thanks for your comment! I do not have an objective measure of the difficulty of the questions. Do you have a different suggestion? Or could I not also run the ANOVA with both treatment groups and in person/online as factors without using the percentage score?

Comment: I can't comment on these things without knowing all the details (what the questions are, how exactly the tests are run and marked, how the people were split up into the two groups),sorry. It may be possible to run the ANOVA as you suggest, but if the scores of the two tests are not comparable, this may cause some trouble.